# Apply condition on a column after groupby in pandas and then aggregate to get 2 max value

Tags: python, pandas

```
data    field   bcorr
0   A   cs1 0.8
1   A   cs2 0.9
2   A   cs3 0.7
3   A   pq1 0.4
4   A   pq2 0.6
5   A   pq3 0.5
6   B   cs1 0.8
7   B   cs2 0.9
8   B   cs3 0.7
9   B   pq1 0.4
10  B   pq2 0.6
11  B   pq3 0.5
```

For every data `A` and `B` in `data` column, segregate the `cs` & `pq` fields from `field` column, and then aggregate to get 2 max value of `bcorr`.

Sample result would be like:

```
data    field   bcorr
0   A   cs1 0.8
1   A   cs2 0.9
4   A   pq2 0.6
5   A   pq3 0.5
6   B   cs1 0.8
7   B   cs2 0.9
10  B   pq2 0.6
11  B   pq3 0.5
```

For this, one of option is to do this while creating the list of records, which obviously will have high complexity.

second, i want to do this with pandas dataframe, where i used `groupby` on `data` column, then applying `startswith` to get the source `field` and then apply `max`

Answer (score 0):

First, extract common part of each field (first letters) then sort values (highest values go bottom). Finally group by `data` column and `field` series then keep the two last values (the highest):

```
field = df['field'].str.extract('([^\d]+)', expand=False)
out = df.sort_values('bcorr').groupby(['data', field]).tail(2).sort_index()
print(out)

# Output
   data field  bcorr
0     A   cs1    0.8
1     A   cs2    0.9
4     A   pq2    0.6
5     A   pq3    0.5
6     B   cs1    0.8
7     B   cs2    0.9
10    B   pq2    0.6
11    B   pq3    0.5
```

If you field have only two fixed letters to determine the field, you can use `df['field'].str[:2]` instead of `df['field'].str.extract(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby` on date and substring field column using `str[:2]` which grabs the characters up to the 2nd, and use `head(2)`.

[`head`](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+head&oq=pandas+head&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i433i512j0i512l3j69i60l3.1752j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) returns the first `n` rows, so you will need to sort the data before.

```
df.sort_values(by=['data','bcorr'],ascending=False).groupby(['data',df.field.str[:2]]).head(2).sort_index()

  data field  bcorr
0     A   cs1    0.8
1     A   cs2    0.9
4     A   pq2    0.6
5     A   pq3    0.5
6     B   cs1    0.8
7     B   cs2    0.9
10    B   pq2    0.6
11    B   pq3    0.5
```

Following the above logic, using `tail(2)` and sorting the data the other way around get's you the same output:

```
df.sort_values(by=['data','bcorr']).groupby(['data',df.field.str[:2]]).tail(2).sort_index()
```

**EDIT**
If you want to generalize to allow for arbitrary number of non digit characters in your field column, you could use `str.replace` to replace all numeric characters with empty in your `groupby`:

```
df.sort_values(by=['data','bcorr']).groupby(['data',df.field.str.replace(r"[0-9]",'')]).tail(2).sort_index()
```

Comment: not getting the max bcorr

Comment: Edited the answer. there was a need to sort the values before.

Comment: would have been great if we can generalize `df.field.str[:2]` part. it will not work if we have field starting from `cs`, `abc`.

Comment: no it won't if you have more than 2 characters to group on. but if you have that, you can groupby only using the non digit characters, which should work

Comment: I have edited the answer to allow for that flexibility, kindly have a look. You could also have a look at @Corralien's answer, it is also allowing for this flexibility.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is something you are trying to achieve

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'data': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
      'fie': ['cs1', 'cs2', 'cs3', 'pq1', 'pq2', 'pq3', 'cs1', 'cs2', 'cs3', 'pq1', 'pq2', 'pq3'],
      'bcorr': [0.8, 0.9, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5]}

df = {'data': df['data'], 'fie_c': [x[:2] for x in df['fie']], 'fie_n': [x[2] for x in df['fie']],
      'bcorr': df['bcorr']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
df = df.sort_values('bcorr', ascending=False).groupby(by=['data', 'fie_c']).head(2).sort_values('data')
df['fie'] = df[['fie_c', 'fie_n']].apply(lambda x: '{}{}'.format(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
df = df.drop(columns=['fie_c', 'fie_n'])
df = df[['data', 'fie', 'bcorr']]
print(df)
```

Output

```
   data  fie  bcorr
1     A  cs2    0.9
0     A  cs1    0.8
4     A  pq2    0.6
5     A  pq3    0.5
7     B  cs2    0.9
6     B  cs1    0.8
10    B  pq2    0.6
11    B  pq3    0.5
```

Note that the first few lines can be more cleaner but my focus was on the line

```
df = df.sort_values('bcorr', ascending=False).groupby(by=['data', 'fie_c']).head(2).sort_values('data')
```

which does most of the important work.